# How to reorganize rows?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have data in the format

```
Id  Value
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h
9   i
10  j
11  k
12  l
13  m
14  n
15  o
16  p
```

and i want it to appear as

```
1   a        5   e        9   i        13  m
2   b        6   f        10  j        14  n
3   c        7   g        11  k        15  o
4   d        8   h        12  l        16  p
```

So I'd like to turn this 2x16 table into a 8x4 table

If possible, I'd like to exclude the column headers entirely and also exclude the number column but still use it for sorting.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you trying to do this?  What presentation layer (SSRS, Excel, Power BI, etc) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Grafana

Comment: Haven't come across that one, but surely it can pivot a dataset for you?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Any decent reporting suite should be able to emulate the pivot tables you get in Excel

Answer (score 0):

If your presentation software can pivot data, you can provide a grouping value for your required column layout by using a `row_number` ordered on your `Id` column and a modulo operation for the number of rows you require:

```
declare @t table(Id int,Value varchar(1));
insert into @t values(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),(6,'f'),(7,'g'),(8,'h'),(9,'i'),(10,'j'),(11,'k'),(12,'l'),(13,'m'),(14,'n'),(15,'o'),(16,'p');

select Id
    ,Value
    ,(row_number() over (order by Id)-1) % 4 as ColGroup
from @t
order by Id;
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+----------+
| Id | Value | ColGroup |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | a     |        0 |
|  2 | b     |        1 |
|  3 | c     |        2 |
|  4 | d     |        3 |
|  5 | e     |        0 |
|  6 | f     |        1 |
|  7 | g     |        2 |
|  8 | h     |        3 |
|  9 | i     |        0 |
| 10 | j     |        1 |
| 11 | k     |        2 |
| 12 | l     |        3 |
| 13 | m     |        0 |
| 14 | n     |        1 |
| 15 | o     |        2 |
| 16 | p     |        3 |
+----+-------+----------+
```

---

The `-1` is there to ensure the `ColGroup` values start at the first column rather than the second.

Answer (score 0):

By understanding,

```
create table #t (Id int,Value varchar(1));
insert into #t values(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),(6,'f'),(7,'g'),(8,'h'),(9,'i'),(10,'j'),(11,'k'),(12,'l'),(13,'m'),(14,'n'),(15,'o'),(16,'p');

select ot.Id1 '1', ot.Id2 '2', thf.Id3 '3', thf.Id4 '4' 
from(
 select * from(
  select Id Id1, Value Value1  from #t
 )o 
 join (
  select Id Id2, Value Value2 from #t
 )t 
 on o.Id1 = t.Id2 - 4
)ot
join(
 select * from(
  select Id Id3, Value Value3 from #t
 )th                              
 join (                           
  select Id Id4, Value Value4 from #t
 )f
 on th.Id3 = f.Id4 - 4
)thf
on ot.Id2 = thf.Id3 - 4
```

Here your `id`column must in int column. If non-int column, then you can use `row_number()` instead of id column in conditions. As,

```
select Id Id3, Value Value3, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) rn3 from #t
//join query
on th.rn3 = f.rn4 - 4
```

Let me know, what your got..!

Thanks, 
TamilPugal